# Generate a list of zeros and ones by comparing two different lists of integers in python

Tags: python, list

I recently got started in Python and have the following problem which I will try best to explain in words:

I have two different lists as below:

```
    list_a = [1,2,3,4,5]
    list_b = [[2,5],[1,4]]
```

I would like to compare both lists and generate a third list such that for each number in each list in list_b, if the number equals the corresponding number in list_a, a one is generated and where there is no match, a zero is generated.

The length of each list in my output list should equal the length of list_a (i.e. length of 5, a one where there is a match and a zero if there is no match).

Therefore the output list that I am seeking should be as follows:

```
    out = [[0,1,0,0,1],[1,0,0,1,0]]
```

Would greatly appreciate if you could help me out. Thanks!

Comment: First question, can list_a ever take the form of ```[2,5,3,1,4]```?

Comment: Second question, can list_a ever take the form of ```[12, 123, 696, 1, 84393]``` or does it have to be consecutive numbers starting with 1?

Comment: Please update your question with the code that you have tried.

Comment: @LazyCoder what is the difference in the form between the two lists you just mentioned?

Comment: I am trying to understand if there is actually a dependency between list_a and list_b or @GThomas is trying to vectorize numbers unknowingly.

Comment: @LazyCoder in this situation, list_a has to be consecutive numbers starting from 1 and ending at 5. In addition, all numbers in each list in list_b fall only between 1 and 5.

Comment: So list_a is not really needed/important, just knowledge about that your sublists should have length 5...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nested list comprehensions

```
[[int(el in list_b_el) for el in list_a] for list_b_el in list_b]
```

result

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: `int(el in list_b_el)`.

Comment: Could you leverage the fact that final value of output has nothing to do with list_a?

Comment: Of course the final value has something to do with list_a since i check whether every value of list_a is in a list element of nested list_b. Check this part `[int(el in list_b_el) for el in list_a]`

Comment: I did it similarly but maybe easier to read `answer=[[1 if x in y else 0 for x in list_a] for y in list_b]`

Comment: I actually used that too before I adapted due to @chepner comment. I think that's easier to read and pretty common in python to use.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple loops in a list comprehension can get a bit confusing to read so it's easier to write the loops out for readability:

```
result = []
for b in list_b:
    sublist = []
    for a in list_a:
        if a in b:
            sublist.append(1)
        else: 
            sublist.append(0)
    result.append(sublist)
```

Comment: @Akaisteph7 thank you for suggesting that is this better?

Comment: Comments aren't necessary with such simple code. The description of why you think this is a good answer is good though.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 5-zeros-list for every sublist in `list_b` and then only iterate over the numbers in each sublist using them as index to switch those zeros to `1`:

```
list_b = [[2,5],[1,4]]

out = []
for lb in list_b:
    out.append([0]*5)
    for idx in lb:
        out[-1][idx-1] = 1
```

---

**Performance**
If anybody is interested in execution speed, here's a glance at the timings:

```
def pythonic():
    [[int(el in list_b_el) for el in list_a] for list_b_el in list_b]

def Tyger():
    result = []
    for b in list_b:
        sublist = []
        for a in list_a:
            if a in b:
                sublist.append(1)
            else: 
                sublist.append(0)
        result.append(sublist)

def SpghttCd():
    out = []
    for lb in list_b:
        out.append([0]*5)
        for idx in lb:
            out[-1][idx-1] = 1
```

```
list_a = [1,2,3,4,5]
list_b = [[2,5],[1,4]]

%timeit pythonic()
%timeit Tyger()
%timeit SpghttCd()
3.03 µs ± 147 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
1.63 µs ± 10.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
1.02 µs ± 9.64 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Now with these short sublists in `list_b` the functions `SpghttCd` and `Tyger` have much less iterations than `pythonic`, so a worst case trial:

```
list_a = [1,2,3,4,5]
list_b = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]

%timeit pythonic()
%timeit Tyger()
%timeit SpghttCd()
3.03 µs ± 56.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
1.8 µs ± 103 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
1.53 µs ± 13.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```